# Setting the Default Search Provider on Chrome via a script

Tags: google-chrome

I am attempting to set various Google Chrome preferences via a script (on both OS X and Windows). I can successfully set a number of preferences, and add bookmarks, by editing the Preferences and Bookmarks json files in the user's Application Data folder. However, when i attempt to set a new default search provider, the browser automatically reverts to Google search.

The default search provider node in the Preferences file looks like this:

```
"default_search_provider": {
    "enabled": true,
    "encodings": "UTF-8",
    "icon_url": "http://www.google.com/favicon.ico",
    "id": "2",
    "instant_url": "{google:baseURL}webhp?{google:RLZ}sourceid=chrome-instant&ie={inputEncoding}&ion=1{searchTerms}&nord=1",
    "keyword": "google.com",
    "name": "Google",
    "prepopulate_id": "1",
    "search_url": "{google:baseURL}search?{google:RLZ}{google:acceptedSuggestion}{google:originalQueryForSuggestion}sourceid=chrome&ie={inputEncoding}&q={searchTerms}",
    "suggest_url": "{google:baseSuggestURL}search?client=chrome&hl={language}&q={searchTerms}"
}
```

In order to add my desired search provider, I've simply added it manually (via the wrench menu), viewed the effect of this action on the json file, and then written a script to mimic these changes. However, when I change it via a script, the default search provider is used for the first search, but then resets the next time chrome is started. What am i missing here?

Comment: Have you found a solution? I am looking to change this from a Chrome Extension.

Answer (score 4):

as mentioned, you should edit the `'Web Data'` file, which is an sqlite database.

To add a search engine, add an entry to the `'keywords'` table.
To change the default search engine, edit the `'Default Search Provider ID`' value inside the `'meta'` table.

Comment: Hi, i tried the same but could not accomplish the required. Could you please share any resource where I can get a better guidance to this solution implementation.. Also Web Data file writing from browser would need ActiveX control.. this again is a territory i wouldn't want to step in

Comment: @var17 I'm not sure what do you mean by ".. would need ActiveX control..."  
  
To edit an sqlite database you can either use a dedicated application (such as a [command line shell](http://sqlite.org/cli.html)) or use an API for your prefered language (such as [API for C](http://www.sqlite.org/capi3ref.html) or [for python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html))  
  
Any way,  
  
This question is quite old, so I'm not sure if the solution still works.  
Let me know if it worked for you !

Comment: adding engine to keywords table added the searchengine in my defaults list. But adding key to meta table did not set it to default

Comment: Well that's a good start! I would suggest setting manually different search engines as default AND query these tables after each change. This could give you an idea of what should be done next.

Comment: Still no luck. Tries\d the meta file and changing preferences file. Could you please confirm that the ID to be inserted for 'Default Search Provider ID' is row id of keywords table or sync_guid

Comment: It sounds reasonable but I honestly don't know. As I told you, this question is quite old and it is possible that the tables format has changed.

Answer (score 4):

Despite everybody here suggesting to write to Chrome's Sqlite DB, the same can be achieved via JSON based config files (as noted above by https://stackoverflow.com/users/49572/andreas-huber).

The relevant documentation can be found here:

- https://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-templates
- https://www.chromium.org/administrators/linux-quick-start
- https://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#DefaultSearchProvider

For Chrome on Linux putting something like this into `/opt/chrome/etc/policies/recommended/duckduckgo.json` shoud get you started:

```
{
        "DefaultSearchProviderEnabled": true,
        "DefaultSearchProviderName": "DuckDuckGo",
        "DefaultSearchProviderSearchURL": "https://duckduckgo.com/?q={searchTerms}"
}
```

On Windows and OSX and with Chromium the places to set this are different, but are all documented under the above given URLs.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change the default search provider in Google Chrome you have to modify 'Web Data' file wich is an SQLite file.

On my computer the location where you can find the file is `C:\Users\daniel\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default`(Windows7).

See the content of file with SQLite Database Browser; you can find one [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/).

Comment: Which table is the default search provider in?  Is it web_apps?

Answer (score 1):

A solution that is working for Chromium and Chrome on Ubuntu can be found here:

https://github.com/andreashuber69/os-setup/blob/master/common/reset-browser-preferences

Besides setting the default search provider, the linked script further customizes Chromium/Chrome to my liking. For Chrome, the part relevant to the question goes like this:

```
# Modify the preferences relevant to the default search provider
cat ~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Preferences | jq '.default_search_provider_data.template_url_data={ "keyword": "duckduckgo.com", "short_name": "DuckDuckGo", "suggestions_url": "https://duckduckgo.com/ac/?q={searchTerms}&type=list", "url": "https://duckduckgo.com/?q={searchTerms}&t=canonical" }' >adapted-preferences.json
mv adapted-preferences.json ~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Preferences
```

This simply adds a new entry to the list of search engines and sets it as default. If you want to select an existing one, things are little more complicated (see script for details). The above requires the package jq, which is not present out of the box on Ubuntu.

Contrary to other posts, it seems no longer possible to set the default in the meta table. It must be done through the Preferences file as shown above.