# Adding a custom search engine to chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've just started writing chrome extensions . Now i've hit a block . I understand that all the chrome data is stored in a SQLite database called WEB DATA.

Now based on some input in the omnibar , i need to insert a few records to a table in this WEB DATA .

Do you know how this can be done programatically when chrome is open ? Because we can go to options -> Manage search engines -> and add a new search engine to the bottom . How does chrome do this behind the scenes ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have seen you leaving messages in some threads talking about SQLite, WEB DATA and "Chrome is open/close" and using those terms is really confusing. If you can use other words to describe those concepts I am sure it would make your question more accurate and understandable.
In any case, any local data of that sort can only be modified by the known APIs.

Answer (score 1):

Download and extract sqlite-tools-win32-x86-3240000.zip.

First, add the the Search Provider from within Google Chrome:

- Right-click the address-bar and select "Edit search engines...";
- In the page "chrome://settings/searchEngines", click "Add";
- Enter search engine name, keyword and search URL (e.g. DuckDuckGo, duckduckgo.com, https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%s), click "Add";
- **Close** Google Chrome;

Open an Windows Command Prompt (cmd.exe). Type the following command:

```
sqlite3.exe "%LOCALAPPDATA\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Web Data"
```

(whereas "web Data" is the actual sqlite-database file)

The file is opened with sqlite. Now type the following command to export the search engines to a .CSV-file:

```
sqlite> .headers on
sqlite> .mode csv
sqlite> .output C:/keywords_table.csv
sqlite> SELECT * FROM keywords;
sqlite> .quit
```

Open the the .CSV-file and notice the last line:
6,DuckDuckGo,duckduckgo.com,https://duckduckgo.com/favicon.ico,https://duckduckgo.com/?q={searchTerms},0,"",13173455944766115,0,"","",0,0,13173455944766115,2bb9a9bf-8921-421a-89b4-06deeaaf0742,[],"","","","","",0

Use the information from the .CSV-file to add the new search engine to Google Chrome (again from Windows Command Prompt):

```
sqlite3.exe "%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\continuousUpdates\User Data\Default\Web Data" "INSERT INTO keywords VALUES(6,'DuckDuckGo','duckduckgo.com','https://duckduckgo.com/favicon.ico','https://duckduckgo.com/?q={searchTerms}',0,'',13173455944766115,0,'','',0,0,13173455944766115,'2bb9a9bf-8921-421a-89b4-06deeaaf0742','[]','','','','','',0);"
```

Notice that I have replaces all double quotes with single qoutes and places all string-values within single qoutes as well.

Start Google Chrome and check "chrome://settings/searchEngines" if the new search engine appears in the list "Default search engines" or "Other search engines"

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, You can't directly edit the file while chrome is running. Trying to do so with sqlite3.exe returns 'database is locked' error.

see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10520250/808270) for more info on how to add a search engine