# Chome API manifest dynamic url permission based on default search engine?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is there a way to extract the url for the default search engine (for omnibox) and then include that within the URL permissions scope?

Comment: I've not done any work around the omnibox so I can't help with the URL extraction, but if you're willing to only target Chrome 17 and over you can use [optional permissions](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/permissions.html) to request host permission for that URL.

Answer (score 1):

Quick answer is no, there is no such API to do that. Unless you want to use a NPAPI plugin, which can basically do anything. If so then you can access the default search engine by reading chrome files, according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7872947/754803), it's in a sqlite database.