# Set a default Search Engine for Google Chrome

Tags: c#, .net, google-chrome

I have to develop an exe application that replace the default search engine of Google Chrome and set my private search engine of Google Chrome after installing on that exe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is an API for doing this via JavaScript or else.
However, this might possible by using the SQLite data file and editing it.

The file on typical Windows 7 can be found at:
`C:\Users\ABC\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default`  and file is named as `'Web Data'`.

To add a search engine, add an entry to the `'keywords'` table.
To change the default search engine, edit the `'Default Search Provider ID'` value inside the `'meta'` table.

Note: This method is not officially supported and you may mess up chrome settings.

**Courtesy**: [Setting the Default Search Provider on Chrome via a script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6657472/setting-the-default-search-provider-on-chrome-via-a-script)

Answer (score 2):

Preferences are saved within `Preferences` file in `C:\Users\##UserName##\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default`.

That's a JSON file. You should look for following part of the file:

```
   "default_search_provider": {
      "alternate_urls": [ "{google:baseURL}#q={searchTerms}", "{google:baseURL}search#q={searchTerms}", "{google:baseURL}webhp#q={searchTerms}" ],
      "enabled": true,
      "encodings": "UTF-8",
      "icon_url": "http://www.google.com/favicon.ico",
      "id": "2",
      "image_url": "{google:baseURL}searchbyimage/upload",
      "image_url_post_params": "encoded_image={google:imageThumbnail},image_url={google:imageURL},sbisrc={google:imageSearchSource},original_width={google:imageOriginalWidth},original_height={google:imageOriginalHeight}",
      "instant_url": "{google:baseURL}webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&{google:RLZ}{google:forceInstantResults}{google:instantExtendedEnabledParameter}{google:ntpIsThemedParameter}{google:omniboxStartMarginParameter}ie={inputEncoding}",
      "instant_url_post_params": "",
      "keyword": "google.com",
      "name": "Google",
      "new_tab_url": "{google:baseURL}_/chrome/newtab?{google:RLZ}{google:instantExtendedEnabledParameter}{google:ntpIsThemedParameter}ie={inputEncoding}",
      "prepopulate_id": "1",
      "search_terms_replacement_key": "espv",
      "search_url": "{google:baseURL}search?q={searchTerms}&{google:RLZ}{google:originalQueryForSuggestion}{google:assistedQueryStats}{google:searchFieldtrialParameter}{google:bookmarkBarPinned}{google:searchClient}{google:sourceId}{google:instantExtendedEnabledParameter}{google:omniboxStartMarginParameter}ie={inputEncoding}",
      "search_url_post_params": "",
      "suggest_url": "{google:baseSuggestURL}search?{google:searchFieldtrialParameter}client={google:suggestClient}&xssi=t&q={searchTerms}&{google:cursorPosition}{google:zeroPrefixUrl}{google:pageClassification}sugkey={google:suggestAPIKeyParameter}",
      "suggest_url_post_params": "",
      "synced_guid": "CE1B8BFD-412B-4AB3-B597-325B07CA7E76"
   },
```

*I have no idea how will browser react if you change that file from outside the browser! It's possible that it will be synced back into version stored in cloud when user decided to sync Chrome settings between different machines using Google Account.*